# Replace string in powershell array

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

This is my array :

$array who contains theses values :

```
Y:\155150716070\00000027.JPG
Y:\155150716070\00000028.JPG
Y:\155150716070\00000029.JPG
Y:\155150716070\00000030.JPG
Y:\155150716070\00000031.JPG
Y:\155150716070\00000032.JPG
Y:\155150716070\00000033.JPG
Y:\155150716070\00000034.JPG
Y:\155150716070\00000035.JPG
Y:\155150716070\00000036.JPG
```

How can i replace "`JPG`" by "`TIF`" to get something like that ?

```
Y:\155150716070\00000027.TIF
Y:\155150716070\00000028.TIF
Y:\155150716070\00000029.TIF
Y:\155150716070\00000030.TIF
Y:\155150716070\00000031.TIF
Y:\155150716070\00000032.TIF
Y:\155150716070\00000033.TIF
Y:\155150716070\00000034.TIF
Y:\155150716070\00000035.TIF
Y:\155150716070\00000036.TIF
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 21):

Using `-replace` as an array operator:

```
$array -replace 'JPG$','TIF'
```